# how to check if a google tag is already loaded on an html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a default page and a master page that I am adding google analytics tags to. however, these pages are used by different content pages. so when I add the tags to both pages on a content page it gets added twice.

How do I check if the tag already exists then do not load one of them?

this is my code

```
 <script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
```

so if for example, a test page is using both the default and the master pages HTML then it should only append the Google tags once to the test page. Currently, it gets added twice. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the unminified code?

Answer (score 2):

The below method can be used to check GTM status:

```js
function isGtmLoaded() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    let gtmStartedEvent = window.dataLayer.find(element => element['gtm.start']);
    if (!gtmStartedEvent) {
        return false; // Not even the GTM inline config has executed
    }
    else if (!gtmStartedEvent['gtm.uniqueEventId']) {
        return false; // GTM inline config has ran, but main GTM js is not loaded (likely AdBlock, NoScript, URL blocking etc.)
    }
    return true; // GTM is fully loaded and working
}
```

For explanation see my comments under [mgabor6's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55852701/8349769).

Answer (score 1):

The `window.dataLayer` will exist after it runs once, so you can wrap the above code in an if

```
if(window.dataLayer) {
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');
}
```

Comment: Do I add this onto both the default and master page?

Comment: Note that it is common to initialise `window.dataLayer` in other scripts too e.g. using: `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];` in which case only checking if `window.dataLayer` exists is not enough. Use this instead: `if (window.dataLayer.find(element => element['gtm.start'])) { console.log('added') } else { console.log('not added') }`

Comment: About the above: It seems to be a nice trick, however the `gtm.start` event is added to `window.dataLayer` by the inline part of the GTM script. If NoScript or AdBlock blocks the real loading of GTM from https://www.googletagmanager.com/ `gtm.start` will still be in DataLayer, so this detection method may mistakenly suggest GTM is loaded, but it may be not in those cases.